# Find all ancestors without direct id-parentid in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent-child structure across two tables. The first table has BOM_ID for bills and ITEM_ID for associated children items. The other has BOM_ID and ITEM_ID for the parent item.

I am able to find the first level of parents' ITEM_ID with the following query

```
SELECT item_id
FROM bomversion
WHERE bom_id IN (SELECT bom_id FROM bom WHERE item_id = 1)
```

So, in order to find all ancestors, I would have to repeat this step. I've tried to look at CTE and recursion techniques but all examples have parentid and childid in the same table. I cannot figure this one out.

If 1 is child of 2, 2 is child of 3, 3 is child of 4, and 2 is also child of 5, I am looking for the following result:

| ChildID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |

The starting point will be a specific ChildID.

---

S O L U T I O N

Based on Adnan Sharif's proposal, I found the solution for my problem:

```
WITH items_CTE AS (
  -- create the mapping of items to consider
  SELECT
   B.ITEMID AS Child_id,
   BV.ITEMID AS Parent_Id
  FROM BOM AS B
  INNER JOIN BOMVERSION AS BV
  ON B.BOMID = BV.BOMID
), parent_child_cte AS (
  -- select those items as initial query
  SELECT
    Child_id,
    Parent_id
  FROM items_CTE
  WHERE Child_id = '111599' -- this is the starting point
  UNION ALL
  -- recursive approach to find all the ancestors
  SELECT
   c.Child_Id,
   c.Parent_Id
  FROM items_CTE c
  JOIN parent_child_cte pc
  ON pc.Parent_Id = c.Child_id
)
SELECT * FROM parent_child_cte
```

Comment: does the item_id 6, 7, 8, 9, etc belongs to `bom` table? Could you please simplify what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if they are children of a BOM, then yes, but not necessarily

Comment: In the given example, we are not seeing them in the `bom` table but seeing them in expected result making me confused. Can you please provide a trickier example instead which covers all the edge cases?

Comment: updated for clarity, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: Without examples, it's currently not clear to the other community members. However, how to know that one element is the parent element? Will the Parent_ITEM_ID = Child_ITEM_ID in for the parent items?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is yes. If an item is both a parent and a child, its ITEM_ID is in both tables. Maybe have a look at this:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhCpH9TbAPTRoS8NMxzpqa/1#&togetherjs=9cgES7HcQ7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dbfiddle that you shared in the comment, if I understand you correctly, you want to have the rows showing all the parents of a child.
For example, lets consider the hierarchy, 1 is a child of 2, 2 is a child of 3, and 3 is a child of 4. You want the final result as,

| child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

If that's the case, we can use recursive CTE to build that table. First of all, we need to be build a relation between those two tables based on `bom_id` and then we need to find out parent-child relation. After that we will add rows based on the initial query. Please see the below code.

```
WITH RECURSIVE items_CTE AS (
  -- create the mapping of items to consider
  SELECT
   B.Item_id AS Child_id,
   BV.Item_id AS Parent_Id
  FROM BOM AS B
  INNER JOIN BOMVERSION AS BV
  ON B.bom_id = BV.bom_id
), parent_child_cte AS (
  -- select those items as initial query
  SELECT
    Child_id,
    Parent_id
  FROM items_CTE
  
  UNION
  
  -- recursive approach to find all the ancestors
  SELECT
   parent_child_cte.Child_Id,
   items_CTE.Parent_Id
  FROM items_CTE
  INNER JOIN parent_child_cte
  ON parent_child_cte.Parent_Id = items_CTE.Child_id
)
SELECT * FROM parent_child_cte
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am looking for a result that displays Child-Parent or Parent-Child, direct relationships. Se my updated post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @redhoax glad to help you finding the solution by yourself